# How to add three divs inline with reponsive behaviour?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a Login form but I am in trouble while adding logo above the login box. I have two logos and one text between them and I need that inline with responsive behavior.

I am a PHP developer I have no idea about designing.
How can I achieve a layout like the image below?

```html
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container>.logo {
    flex: 1;
    /*grow*/
  }
</style>

<body class="login-page">

  <!-- Progress Bar -->
  <div class="progress-wrap progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header-container-wrapper">
    <div class="page-center">
      <a href="//www.c2perform.com">
        <img src="images/C2_Perform_Logo_Colour.svg" id="header-logo" alt="C2Perform" title="C2Perform">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Body -->
  <div class="body-container-wrapper">
    <div class="page-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/ef_logo.png" width="200px" height="auto">
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <h4>is now</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/C2_Perform_Logo_Colour.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Login -->
      <div class="login-box-wrapper">
        <div class="login-box">
          <h3>Log In</h3>
          <?php ef_print_notices();  ?>
          <!-- Login Form -->
          <form role="form" method="post" id="loginForm" class="form lostpass">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3">User Name</label>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control validate[required]" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="" size="30" maxlength="225" id="formfocus">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
              <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" size="30" maxlength="25" class="form-control validate[required]" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" name="ef_nonce" value="<?php ef_create_nonce('login_nonce'); ?>" />
              <div>
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="button" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div><a href="./lostpassword.php">Lost Password?</a></div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: desired layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `align-items` for vertical alignment and `justify-content` to align horizontally.

**DEMO**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container>.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div class="progress-wrap progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
</div>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header-container-wrapper">
  <div class="page-center">
    <a href="//www.c2perform.com">
      <img src="images/C2_Perform_Logo_Colour.svg" id="header-logo" alt="C2Perform" title="C2Perform">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="body-container-wrapper">
  <div class="page-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/ef_logo.png" width="200px" height="auto">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>is now</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/C2_Perform_Logo_Colour.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="login-box-wrapper">
      <div class="login-box">
        <h3>Log In</h3>
        <?php ef_print_notices();  ?>
        <!-- Login Form -->
        <form role="form" method="post" id="loginForm" class="form lostpass">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3">User Name</label>
            <div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control validate[required]" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="" size="30" maxlength="225" id="formfocus">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
            <div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" size="30" maxlength="25" class="form-control validate[required]" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="ef_nonce" value="<?php ef_create_nonce('login_nonce'); ?>" />
            <div>
              <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="button" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div><a href="./lostpassword.php">Lost Password?</a></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the display behavior to be grid, and so, so you define the width in which the images should be displayed down.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.container>.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Progress Bar -->
<div class="progress-wrap progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
</div>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header-container-wrapper">
  <div class="page-center">
    <a href="//www.c2perform.com">
      <img src="images/C2_Perform_Logo_Colour.svg" id="header-logo" alt="C2Perform" title="C2Perform">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Body -->
<div class="body-container-wrapper">
  <div class="page-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/ef_logo.png" width="200px" height="auto">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>is now</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/C2_Perform_Logo_Colour.jpg" width="200px" height="auto">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login -->
    <div class="login-box-wrapper">
      <div class="login-box">
        <h3>Log In</h3>
        <?php ef_print_notices();  ?>
        <!-- Login Form -->
        <form role="form" method="post" id="loginForm" class="form lostpass">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3">User Name</label>
            <div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control validate[required]" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="" size="30" maxlength="225" id="formfocus">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
            <div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" size="30" maxlength="25" class="form-control validate[required]" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="ef_nonce" value="<?php ef_create_nonce('login_nonce'); ?>" />
            <div>
              <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="button" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div><a href="./lostpassword.php">Lost Password?</a></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There I say that, whenever the items can have at least 100px of width, the items can remain inline, but, if the items can't achieve that minimum width, those which can't, are displayed down